# Calculating the Standard Deviation of an text file

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the Standard Deviation of all the data thats in the column of "ClosePrices" see the pastebin https://pastebin.com/JtGr672m

We need to calculate one Standard Deviation of all the 1029 floats.

This is my code:

```
ins1 = open("bijlage.txt", "r")
for line in ins1:

        numbers = [(n) for n in number_strings] 
        i = i + 1
        ClosePriceSD = []
        ClosePrice = float(data[0][5].replace(',', '.'))
        ClosePriceSD.append(ClosePrice)

def sd_calc(data):
    n = 1029

    if n <= 1:
        return 0.0

    mean, sd = avg_calc(data), 0.0

    # calculate stan. dev.
    for el in data:
        sd += (float(el) - mean)**2
    sd = math.sqrt(sd / float(n-1))

    return sd

def avg_calc(ls):
    n, mean = len(ls), 0.0

    if n <= 1:
        return ls[0]

    # calculate average
    for el in ls:
        mean = mean + float(el)
    mean = mean / float(n)

    return mean
print("Standard Deviation:")
print(sd_calc(ClosePriceSD))
print()
```

So what I'm trying to calculate is the Standard Deviation of all the floats under the "Closeprices" part.

well I have this "ClosePrice = float(data[0][5].replace(',', '.'))" this should calculate the Standard Deviation from all the floats that are under ClosePrice but it only calculates it from data[0][5]. But I want it to calculate one standard deviation from all the 1029 floats under ClosePrice

Comment: Hello @Jonas, welcome to SO :) Would you please illustrate the issue with your code as you haven't stated so?

Comment: well I have this "ClosePrice = float(data[0][5].replace(',', '.'))" this should calculate the Standard Deviation from all the floats that are under ClosePrice but it only calculates it from data[0][5]. But I want it to calculate one standard deviation from all the 1029 floats under ClosePrice

Comment: Add that to your question text :)

Comment: I just edited it in!

Comment: I think your error might be in the for loop at the beginning. You have `for line in ins1` but then you never use `line` inside the loop. And in your loop you also use `number_string` and `data` which are not defined before. Is there some more code you haven't shown?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really specify what the issue/error is.  Although this probably doesn't help if it is a school project, you could install scipy, which has a [standard deviation function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.std.html).  In this case, just put your array in as a parameter.  Could you elaborate on what you're having trouble with?  Is the current code giving an error?

**Edit:**
Looking at the data, you want the 6th element in each line (ClosePrice).  If your function is working, and all you need is an array of the ClosedPrice's, this is what I would suggest.

```
data = []
lines = []

ins1 = open("bijlage.txt", "r")
lines = [lines.rstrip('\n') for line in ins1]

for line in lines:
    line.split('\;')
    data.append(line[5])

for i in data:
    data[i] = float(data[i])

def sd_calc(data):
    n = 1029

    if n <= 1:
        return 0.0

    mean, sd = avg_calc(data), 0.0

    # calculate stan. dev.
    for el in data:
        sd += (float(el) - mean)**2
    sd = math.sqrt(sd / float(n-1))

    return sd

def avg_calc(ls):
    n, mean = len(ls), 0.0

    if n <= 1:
        return ls[0]

    # calculate average
    for el in ls:
        mean = mean + float(el)
    mean = mean / float(n)

    return mean
print("Standard Deviation:")
print(sd_calc(data))
print()
```

Comment: Oh and I could not use any things like scipy, numpy, statistics.

Comment: I see.  So what I'm hearing from you is that your standard deviation function is working, but it is not calculating it for all your data?

Comment: Yeah exactly like that!

Comment: Thanks Riley, it tells me this now:    lines = [lines.rstrip('\n') for line in ins1]
NameError: name 'lines' is not defined

Comment: Maybe add `lines = []` with `data = []`.

Comment: lines = [lines.rstrip('\n') for line in ins1]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'  I get this now

Comment: Oops.  Change `lines = [lines.rstrip('\n') for line in ins1]` to `lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in ins1]` (Just take out that s)

Comment: Thanks that works, now I get this!     print(sd_calc(ClosePriceSD))
NameError: name 'ClosePriceSD' is not defined

Comment: print(sd_calc(sd))
NameError: name 'sd' is not defined   filling in sd there also doesnt work

Comment: `print(sd_calc(data))`, because we put all our ClosePrices in the `data` array.

Comment: Try `[float(i) for i in data]`.  I edited my answer above to show where to put it.

Comment: Yeah, I edited it in like you showed me but still gives the same error new pastebin: https://pastebin.com/nrz347pW

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe `data = [float(i) for i in data]`.

Comment: TypeError:      data = [float(i) for i in data]
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Comment: Check the changes I made

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is in the for loop at the beginning. You have `for line in ins1` but then you never use `line` inside the loop. And in your loop you also use `number_string` and `data` which are not defined before.

Here is how you can extract the data from you txt file.

```
with open("bijlage.txt", "r") as ff:
    ll = ff.readlines() #extract a list, each element is a line of the file

data = []
for line in ll[1:]: #excluding the first line wich is an header
    d = line.split(';')[5] #split each line in a list using semicolon as a separator and keep the element with index 5
    data.append(float(d.replace(',', '.'))) #substituting the comma with the dot in the string and convert it to a float

print data #data is a list with all the numbers you want
```

You should be able to calculate mean and standard deviation from here.